# Cannot add a third content field

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I'm kinda new to typo, so maybe I am just missing something.
I'm trying to add a third content field to Typo3 4.5.
What I've done so far.

- Edit my template and added a new block
- Added the block via TemplatVoila > Update Mapping > Modify DS / TO with Element Preset "Page-Content Elements [Pos.: 0]
- Mapped it to the new block in the template

But I am missing something as the new field isn't showing up in the Page edit screen.

EDIT: I've found the Block in the "Edit page properties" but how to show it on standard edit screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any added content area will appear automatically in your TV-View-module. So if you dont see it in there, then

- you may have duplicate fields names
- wrong column positions
- or the existing template is using a »beLayout«-section, which shows only the first two content areas (see example in reference http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/templavoila/ExtTemplavoila/StaticDataStructures/ExampleForBelayout/Index.html)

The TemplaVoila template is split into TS (TemplaVoilà Template Object) and DS (TemplaVoilà Data Structure) records, may you paste the content of the field „Data Structure XML“ of the DS record here? In there are all necessary information.

The two template files should be located in your general storage folder, your TypoScript root file should be there as well.

Comment: Thx for your hin. I really am using such a beLayout. How do I change that? Can't find an option to edit this.

Comment: I've finally figured out where to change that. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.